# Appending frequencies from a corpus to each token in a tweet

Tags: python, nltk, corpus

I am working with tweet data which is POS-tagged with the NLTK POS-tagger. 
My tokens look like:

```
[['wasabi', 'NN'], 
['juice', 'NN']]
```

I also have the American National Corpus Frequencies, a list of words, POS-tags and their frequencies. I would like to look up the word and pos-tag from the tokens, and if it's found, append the frequency from the ANC to the token.

Excellent suggestions from SO have helped, but I found that several of the tokens were not getting frequencies appended (probably because the NLTK tagger is pretty inaccurate, e.g. calling 'silent' a noun, instead of an adjective) and when I tried to append just the frequency, I kept getting a key error, because NLTK had tagged 'jill' as NN, not NNP.

Finally, I decided to take the first frequency if the word is found. The issue now is that I'm getting all the frequencies for occurrences of the word. I just want the first one, so the output would be:

```
[['wasabi', 'NN', '5'], 
['juice', 'NN', '369']]
```

Code,

```py
with open('ANC-all-count.txt', 'r', errors='ignore') as f:
    freqs = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')

    freqs = {}
    for word, pos, f in freq_list:
        if word not in freqs: freqs[word] = {}
        freqs[word][pos] = f

        for i, (word, pos) in enumerate(tokens):
            if word not in freqs: 
                tokens[i].append(0)
                continue
            if pos not in freqs[word]:
                tokens[i] = [tokens[i][0:2]]
                single_token = tokens[i][0]
                if single_token[0] in freqs:
                    tokens[i].append(freqs[word].values())
                continue
            tokens[i].append(freqs[word][pos])
```

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> from collections import Counter

>>> from nltk.corpus import brown
>>> from nltk import pos_tag, word_tokenize

# Access first hundred tokenized sentence from brown corpus
# POS tag these sentences.
>>> tagged_sents = [pos_tag(tokenized_sent) for tokenized_sent in brown.sents()[:100]]

# Sanity check that the tagged_sents are what we want.
>>> list(chain(*tagged_sents))[:10]
[('The', 'DT'), ('Fulton', 'NNP'), ('County', 'NNP'), ('Grand', 'NNP'), ('Jury', 'NNP'), ('said', 'VBD'), ('Friday', 'NNP'), ('an', 'DT'), ('investigation', 'NN'), ('of', 'IN')]

# Use a collections.Counter to get the counts.
>>> freq = Counter(chain(*tagged_sents))

# Top 20 most common words.
>>> dict(freq.most_common(20))
{('the', 'DT'): 128, ('.', '.'): 89, (',', ','): 88, ('of', 'IN'): 67, ('to', 'TO'): 55, ('a', 'DT'): 50, ('and', 'CC'): 40, ('in', 'IN'): 39, ('``', '``'): 35, ("''", "''"): 34, ('The', 'DT'): 28, ('said', 'VBD'): 24, ('that', 'IN'): 24, ('for', 'IN'): 22, ('be', 'VB'): 21, ('was', 'VBD'): 18, ('jury', 'NN'): 17, ('Fulton', 'NNP'): 14, ('election', 'NN'): 14, ('will', 'MD'): 14}

# All the words from most to least common.
>>> dict(freq.most_common())


# To print out the word, pos and counts to file.
>>> with open('freq-counts', 'w') as fout:
...     for (word,pos), count in freq.most_common(20):
...         print('\t'.join([word, pos, str(count)]))
```

Comment: Thank you, but I don't want to find the frequencies relative to other words in the corpus, but relative to a list of frequencies compiled from the American National Corpus.

@inspectorG4dget any insights?